# REST org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file

Tags: rest, soa, bpel, saxparseexception

I use SOA Suite 11g.

1. Composite has component

```
  <component name="ClientPrepare" version="2.0">
    <implementation.bpel src="ClientPrepare.bpel"/>
    <property name="bpel.config.oneWayDeliveryPolicy" type="xs:string"
              many="false">async.persist</property>
  </component>
```

and reference (rest service, get method)

```
  <reference name="PrepareService"
             ui:wsdlLocation="PrepareService.wsdl">
    <interface.wsdl interface="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/http/ClientPrepare/PrepareService#wsdl.interface(ClientPrepare_ptt)"/>
    <binding.ws port="ns#wsdl.endpoint(srv/prt)"
                location="PrepareService.wsdl" supports="http">
      <property name="http.verb" type="xs:string" many="false">GET</property>
      <property name="endpointURI" type="xs:string" many="false">"<some url>"</property>
      <property name="http.payload" type="xs:string" many="false">url-encoded</property>
      <property name="oracle.webservices.http.invocation" type="xs:string" many="false">false</property>
    </binding.ws>
  </reference>
```

2. When component invokes rest service, it receives success http 200, but component process has fault

```
Unable to invoke endpoint URI "<some url>" successfully due to: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to read response: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
```

3. Rest Service receives http header only, without content:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2020 09:03:24 GMT
rlog_pk: 10005254841979
Content-Type: text/html;charset=windows-1251
Content-Language: en
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=999
Server: Oracle-Fusion-Middleware/11g (11.1.1.9) Apache-Coyote/1.1 Oracle-Web-Cache-11g/11.1.1.9.0 (N;ecid=733173134358256,0:1)
Content-Length: 0
```

4. Rest Service response is:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Could you please tell me, what should I do for solving?

Comment: I guess one of the problem is content
`Content-Type: text/html`
from http header of response. Because process waits xml content.
 
I modify wsdl for reference PrepareService with type=text/html , to like that:
            `<wsdl:output>
                <mime:multipartRelated>
                    <mime:part>
                        <mime:content part="res" type="text/html"/>
                    </mime:part>
                </mime:multipartRelated>
            </wsdl:output>`
But when I try recreate HTTP Binding in composite, at 5th step Reply Message Schema is not recognized.